# "What you won't do for" something

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "What you won't do for something" mean that if you want something you have to sacrifice something, for example - your time, or does it not make any sense?

> What you won't do for love

Comment: [I won't do *that*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27d_Do_Anything_for_Love_(But_I_Won%27t_Do_That)). More seriously, it's an incomplete sentence, and might serve as a heading before a list.

Comment: ... but "what you won't do for something perhaps more usually means what you *will* do for something: queue all night, skip class, miss a favourite show...

Comment: @WeatherVane so in other words it means that you do anything to achieve it, right?

Comment: What you've given us doesn't look like the exact words anyone would say in *any* context. But the exclamation ***What John won't do to get laid!*** - means the speaker is astonished at the things John is prepared to do in order to have sex. Is that the construction you're asking about?

Comment: @FumbleFingers ok, I got it, but why noone wouldn't say that in any context?

Comment: @Boyep - plenty of people would say it. It's a normal expression. What wouldn't I do to get the boss's job!

Comment: You miusunderstand my comment. I meant no-one would be likely to say *What you won't do for **something**!* - in the real world, "something" has to actually ***be*** something - for example, *You're **really** addicted to nicotine! What you won't do for a **cigarette**!* OR (my preferred verb form) *What I **wouldn't** give for a good hot meal!*

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Your subject/verb inversion means that's a rhetorical question. But semantically, it's *so* much of an exclamation that one would usually be written with a shebang rather than a question mark

Comment: @FumbleFingers oh, yeah, i just got it wrong, sorry, now I completely figured it out, thank you for help again!

Comment: @Boyep: *What a relief!* :)